# Angular get headers from excel uploaded using XLSX

Tags: excel, angular, file-upload, import, xlsx

I want to get the first row(name,email,mobile) as array from an uploaded excel file.

> I am using XLSX.

I am getting whole data into array. But, I want only to read top line. because,

> my excel file is quite large.

[image]

```js
onFileChange(event) { //when user uploads xls file
    const fileList: FileList = event.target.files;
    if (fileList.length > 0) {
      const file: File = fileList[0];
      const reader = new FileReader();
      reader.onload = function (e) {
        const arrayBuffer = this.result,
          data = new Uint8Array(arrayBuffer),
          arr = new Array();
        for (let i = 0; i !== data.length; ++i) {
          arr[i] = String.fromCharCode(data[i]);
        }    
        const bstr = arr.join('');

        const workbook: XLSX.WorkBook = XLSX.read(bstr, { type: 'binary' });
        const firstSheetName: string = workbook.SheetNames[0];
        const worksheet: XLSX.WorkSheet = workbook.Sheets[firstSheetName];
        // getting all rows
        console.log(XLSX.utils.sheet_to_json(worksheet, { header: 1 })); 
        // I want to get top row only.
        console.log(XLSX.utils.decode_row('A1')); 

      };
      reader.readAsArrayBuffer(file);
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am using this code for single row header in excel sheet, but I want a two row header.  Suggestions are welcome.

```
var Heading =[
  [ "EMPLOYEE","SCORES","COMMENTS"]  
];
  
const myworksheet: XLSX.WorkSheet = XLSX.utils.json_to_sheet(this.emp ,{skipHeader:true});
XLSX.utils.sheet_add_json(myworksheet,this.emp,{skipHeader:true , origin: 'A2'});
XLSX.utils.sheet_add_aoa(myworksheet, Heading);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
function get_header_row(sheet) 
{
    var headers = [];
    var range = XLSX.utils.decode_range(sheet['!ref']);
    var C, R = range.s.r; 
     * start in the first row */
    /* walk every column in the range */
    for(C = range.s.c; C <= range.e.c; ++C) 
   {
        var cell = sheet[XLSX.utils.encode_cell({c:C, r:R})] 

        /* find the cell in the first row */
        var hdr = "UNKNOWN " + C; // <-- replace with your desired default 
        if(cell && cell.t) 
         hdr = XLSX.utils.format_cell(cell);

        headers.push(hdr);
    }
    return headers;
}
```

Comment: You can get the headers within the range by using the code sample above

Answer (score 1):

I've tried the file upload and below is my steps and result with both data and header,

This will also support multiple sheet within the excel sheet,

```
1.npm install --save xlsx
    
2.import * as XLSX from 'xlsx';

3.HTML Code:

<input type="file" (change)="onFileChange($event)">

4.Angular Typescript:

  exceltoJson = {};

  onFileChange(event: any) {
    this.exceltoJson = {};
    let headerJson = {};
    /* wire up file reader */
    const target: DataTransfer = <DataTransfer>(event.target);
    // if (target.files.length !== 1) {
    //   throw new Error('Cannot use multiple files');
    // }
    const reader: FileReader = new FileReader();
    reader.readAsBinaryString(target.files[0]);
    console.log("filename", target.files[0].name);
    this.exceltoJson['filename'] = target.files[0].name;
    reader.onload = (e: any) => {
      /* create workbook */
      const binarystr: string = e.target.result;
      const wb: XLSX.WorkBook = XLSX.read(binarystr, { type: 'binary' });
      for (var i = 0; i < wb.SheetNames.length; ++i) {
        const wsname: string = wb.SheetNames[i];
        const ws: XLSX.WorkSheet = wb.Sheets[wsname];
        const data = XLSX.utils.sheet_to_json(ws); // to get 2d array pass 2nd parameter as object {header: 1}
        this.exceltoJson[`sheet${i + 1}`] = data;
        const headers = this.get_header_row(ws);
        headerJson[`header${i + 1}`] = headers;
        //  console.log("json",headers)
      }
      this.exceltoJson['headers'] = headerJson;
      console.log(this.exceltoJson);
    };
  }

  get_header_row(sheet) {
    var headers = [];
    var range = XLSX.utils.decode_range(sheet['!ref']);
    var C, R = range.s.r; /* start in the first row */
    /* walk every column in the range */
    for (C = range.s.c; C <= range.e.c; ++C) {
      var cell = sheet[XLSX.utils.encode_cell({ c: C, r: R })] /* find the cell in the first row */
      // console.log("cell",cell)
      var hdr = "UNKNOWN " + C; // <-- replace with your desired default 
      if (cell && cell.t) {
        hdr = XLSX.utils.format_cell(cell);
        headers.push(hdr);
      }
    }
    return headers;
  }

5.Result
{filename: "uploadedexcel.xlsx", sheet1: Array(212), sheet2: Array(8), headers: {…}}
```

Results holds the uploaded excel name, data in the sheet1 and sheet2 and also header in the sheet1 and sheet2.

The uploaded excel sheets has sheet1 and sheet2.

Answer (score 0):

Here i am taking  excel sheet  from the blob

public DisplayExcelRows(ExcelURL from blob) {

```
var url = ExcelURL; 
var oReq = new XMLHttpRequest();
oReq.open("GET", url, true);
oReq.responseType = "arraybuffer";
var excelrows: any;

oReq.onload = () => {
  var arraybuffer = oReq.response;

  /* convert data to binary string */
  var data = new Uint8Array(arraybuffer);
  var arr = new Array();
  for (var i = 0; i != data.length; ++i) arr[i] = String.fromCharCode(data[i]);
  var bstr = arr.join("");

  /* Call XLSX */
  var workbook = XLSX.read(bstr, { type: "binary" });

  /* DO SOMETHING WITH workbook HERE */
  var first_sheet_name = workbook.SheetNames[0];
  /* Get worksheet */
  var worksheet = workbook.Sheets[first_sheet_name];
  excelrows = XLSX.utils.sheet_to_json(worksheet, { header: 1 });

  //this will extract headers and other rows separately

  this.data = excelrows;
  this.header = this.data.shift(); //splitting headers and other rows


}
```

Answer (score 0):

simplest way i found of doing this if you are using the json method then that is already generating objects with KEYS from the header so when using:

```
this.decoded = utils.sheet_to_json(workSheet);
```

just do this to get headers (assuming there was anything decoded):

```
this.columns = Object.keys(this.decoded[0]);
```

that will give you the columns, simply by getting the object keys which it used  to generate them from the column names initially

Answer (score -1):

```
// getting all rows
this.data = (XLSX.utils.sheet_to_json(worksheet, { header: 1 })); 
// Fetch the first row
const header = this.data.shift();
```